# EF Core return base class and derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have a SQL table which I want to return some columns always (the props in my base class) and then depending on the result of one of the fields returned (p.CPTCode == "90791") I would like to return a different object containing different fields from the same database table.

Here's what I tried

```
var results = await dbContext.Set<SessionsTable>()
                    .Where(p => p.UniqueID == note_id )
                    .Select(p => p.CPTCode == "90791"
                         ? (SessionNoteBaseClass) new SessionNoteTypeA
                         {
                             UniqueId = p.UniqueID,
                             SesDate = p.SesDate,
                             SesAbs = p.SesAbs,
                             StartTime = p.StartTime,
                             EndTime = p.EndTime,
                             //some more unique fields here
                         }
                         : (SessionNoteBaseClass) new SessionNoteTypeB
                         {
                             UniqueId = p.UniqueID,
                             SesDate = p.SesDate,
                             SesAbs = p.SesAbs,
                             StartTime = p.StartTime,
                             EndTime = p.EndTime,
                             //some more unique fields
                            
                        }).ToListAsync();
```

The `SessionNoteBaseClass` has all the common fields that I would like to return, and `SessionNoteTypeA` class and `SessionNoteTypeB` class each have unique fields that I want to return conditionally.

Each extends the base class:

```
public class SessionNoteTypeA : SessionNoteBaseClass {}
public class SessionNoteTypeB : SessionNoteBaseClass {}
```

**Edit**

the base class

```
public class SessionNoteBaseClass 
{
     public string? UniqueId { get; set; }
     public DateTime? SesDate { get; set; }
     public string? SesAbs { get; set; }
     public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
     public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

SessionNoteTypeA class

```
public class SessionNoteTypeA : SessionNoteBaseClass 
{
    public string? Initial { get; set; } = null;
    public string? InitialReason { get; set; } = null
}
```

SessionNoteTypeB class

```
public class SessionNoteTypeB : SessionNoteBaseClass 
{
    public string? Notes{ get; set; } = null;
    public string? TeleHealth{ get; set; } = null;
}
```

Why am I only getting the fields from the base class returned, and not the additional fields added in the derived classes?

**Another Edit**
SessionsTable class contains all columns from the table (there are around 100) and what im trying to do in my code is to have a request class that maps to my table in the DB, and response classes with specific columns i want returned based on the Cptcode.

So the baseClass is columns i always want to return amd the derived classes are the conditional columns that sometimes i want and sometimes not

Comment: Show definition of `SessionsTable` and what is  "*some more unique fields here*"?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i edited the question to include class definitions. and more unique fields mean class specific fields that are not in the base class, hope this helps..

Comment: `((SessionNoteTypeA)p).Initial` - such access do you need?

Comment: EF Core is an ORM, not a data access library. It deals with *objects* not tables and loads `SessionNoteBaseClass`, `SessionNoteTypeA` and `SessionNoteTypeB` objects. Instead of `Set<SessionsTable>()` you should use `Set<SessionNoteBaseClass>()` and properly configure inheritance in the *model configuration*. EF will take care of constructing the correct subtype based on the data and configuration

Comment: `not the additional fields added in the derived classes?` because none of the `SessionNote` classes is derived from `SessionsTable`. Storing the parent and derived classes is called Table Per Hierarcy. Configuring this is described in [Table-per-hierarchy and discriminator configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i updated my question to explain better what im trying to do. sorry for my bad explanation skills...